# Regex for parsing a simple sentence words delimited by double quotes

Tags: regex, parsing, sentence

I have an example sentence that looks like this:

`""Music"",""EDM / Electronic"",""organizer: Tiny Toons""`

I want to parse this sentence into the tokens:

`["Music", "EDM / Electronic", "organizer: Tiny Toons"]`

My regex foo is quite limited, and I'm under some time pressure.

Was wondering if someone could help me construct a regex (compatible with Java8 - as I'm using Clojure to apply the regex) to parse out these capture groups.

Thank you,
Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the sentence is the entire string and that there are no commas or `"` to be matched, you could just use

```java
"[^,\"]+"
```

If the above assumptions are not correct, please give examples of possible input strings and details of what characters can appear within the sections you want to match.

A simple java example of how to use the regex:

```java
String sentence = "\"\"Music\"\",\"\"EDM / Electronic\"\",\"\"organizer: Tiny Toons\"\"";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^,\"]+").matcher(sentence);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeM that's exactly what I want, I don't want to match the extra double quotes but just the inside quotes, appreciate the response.

A quick clarification, why should I not use a capture group here? I tried `#"(\"\"[^\"]*\"\")*"` but I get too many hits

Comment: @jasonmac Capture groups are used when you want to capture, for later reference, separate sections of a larger match, but there is no need for any larger match here. In your regex, the capture group would only capture the last match of the pattern within the parentheses anyway. For simple grouping it is more efficient to use `(?:)` rather than `()`. Also, your regex will match the empty string because you use `*` rather than `+`.